# Are reduced relative clauses still a subordinate clauses building a complex sentence?

Tags: relative-clauses, subordinate-clauses, complex-sentences

Do relative clauses count as dependent clauses after reduction? Or is it different case by case? for example:

*The man who is in the house is my father.* (complex sentence)
*The man in the house is my father.* (Still a complex sentence?)

*The Evening Show which is airing this month has a new host.* (a complex sentence)
*The Evening Show airing this month has a new host.* (Still a complex sentence?)

What about appositives?

*Her hair, which is long and golden, reflected the sunlight.* (a complex sentence)
*Her hair, long and golden, reflected the sunlight.* (Still a complex sentence

Comment: First: there is no such thing as a 'reduced relative clause'. "The man in the house is my father" is a simple sentence. The subject is the noun phrase "the man in the house" which consists of the head noun "man" modified by the preposition phrase "in the house". "Airing this month" is a gerund-participial clause modifying "Evening Show", so this is a complex sentence. There is no appositive noun phrase in your last example.

Comment: @BillJ In many places you can find the phrase "reduced relative clause" such as in "Grammar and Beyond" book. Regarding the last sentence, I know appositives are supposed to be noun phrases, but this example was mentioned somewhere as an adjectival appositive. Nonetheless, the question remains, are appositives, dependent clauses or just noun phrases?!

Comment: You will find references to 'reduced relatives', but as I explained the term is a misnomer, since they lack the crucial properties of relative clauses.  Some grammars are simply wrong about this. Appositives are NPs.

Comment: I actually took the time to look up "Grammar and Beyond". All I can say is that you would be well-advised to avoid it. It is full of errors, and old out-of-date advice.